# Angular CLI version for Angular 4.4.6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am going through angular 4.4.6 documentation and I want to install the same version in my system, but when i do

> npm install -g @angular/cli

It installs the latest CLI i.e. 1.5.5 and whenever i create the projects on angular, my angular version is v5.0.5 which is the latest angular version.
Which angular/cli version should I use for Angular 4.4.6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want @angular/cli version 1.4.9:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.4.9
```

Checkout the branches and tags on the [GitHub project site](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and open package.json to find out which version of @angular is supported by each CLI release: